# Showing a database extracted array in a message box

Tags: sql, excel, vba, ms-access

I need to show a group of records from an Access database in a message box or any form that is only for view without adding sheets to the workbook.

The information is divided into 9 fields, and are up to 15 rows per entry. I've tried several forms of showing the information, but they don't work, or add another sheet to the workbook. The environment where the workbook is used is only for data and printing capture. Apparently, I already have covered the database connection, the only issue is the display of the information.

```vb
Private Sub Srch_Click()
 Dim A As Object, rs As Object, sSQL As String, CN As String, Arr As Variant, FL As Long, txt As String, i As Long
 FL = tbFolio.Value - 1
    Set A = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    CN = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
        "Data Source=S:\Common\Quality\RASTREABILIDAD\MAIN PROJECT\PROYECTO KOREANO MX.accdb;"
    sSQL = "SELECT * FROM Trazabilidad WHERE Folio = " & (FL) & ";"
    A.Open CN
    Set rs = A.Execute(sSQL)
    Arr = rs.GetRows
    MsgBox Arr, vbOKOnly, Trazabilidad

    rs.Close
    A.Close
Unload Me
End Sub
```

In the debugging, the highlighted section of the code is this:

```vb
MsgBox Arr, vbOKOnly, Trazabilidad
```

The error message is

> "Error '13': Type mismatch"

I've been breaking my mind over how to do it, and I would appreciate any help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Arr` is a 2 dimensional array, there is no automatic way to represent this as a string to show a user.  If you want a string you need to loop over the array (or `rs` directly) and build you own.

Comment: Also `Trazabilidad` should be `"Trazabilidad"`. Your `MsgBox` will have `0` for a title otherwise. Put `Option Explicit` at the top of the module, and declare every variable you're using.

Comment: @AlexK. and what other options exist if it isn't a string? I'm really new to VBA and don't know very well the lenguaje.

Answer (score 1):

[@Alex K. is right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56565737/showing-a-database-extracted-array-in-a-messagebox#comment99711066_56565737) saying a good solution is to loop over the recordset.

But you may also find useful to copy the data to a sheet and then work over it using this code:

```vb
mysheet.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs
```